# Автопостинг фоток в istagram через api

Tags: instagram

Есть ли на данный момент возможность постить фотки со своего сайта в инста через api наподобие как это было http://phpbl.ru/php/instagram-api-avtomaticheskij-posting.html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет. [Тут](https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/) по-прежнему пишут:

> At this time, uploading via the API is not possible.

Объясняют это взвешенное решение так (мой кривой перевод):

- Инстаграм – про вашу жизнь, как она идёт. Мы хотим, чтобы фото загружали из приложения.
- Мы боремся со спамом и низкосортными фотографиями. Если мы разрешим загрузку, станет сложнее контролировать, что попадает в Инстаграм.